# Python - Beautifulsoup count only outer tag children of a tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

HTML of page:

```
<form name="compareprd" action="">
    <div class="gridBox product " id="quickLookItem-1">
        <div class="gridItemTop">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gridBox product " id="quickLookItem-2">
        <div class="gridItemTop">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- many more like this. -->
```

I am using Beautiful soup to scrap a page. In that page I am able to get a form tag by its name.

```
tag = soup.find("form", {"name": "compareprd"})
```

Now I want to count all immediate child divs but not all nested divs.
Say for example there are 20 immediate divs inside form.
I tried :

```
len(tag.findChildren("div"))
```

But It gives 1500.

I think it gives all "div" inside "form" tag.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You think correct, pass [`recursive=False`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument) to `findChildren` in order to find only the direct children. Your HTML seems like tag soup though, you don't close the `div.gridBox` tags.

Comment: Thanks!.Ah Sorry my bad I wrote example code wrong. Updated the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single  *css selector* `form[name=compareprd] > div` which will find *div's* that are immediate children of the form:

```
html  = """<form name="compareprd" action="">
<div class="gridBox product " id="quickLookItem-1">
    <div class="gridItemTop">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="gridBox product " id="quickLookItem-2">
    <div class="gridItemTop">
    </div>
</div>
</form>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)


print(len(soup.select("form[name=compareprd] > div")))
```

Or as commented pass *recursive=True* but use  *find_all*, [findChildren](https://github.com/JinnLynn/beautifulsoup/blob/master/bs4/element.py#L1178) goes back to the bs2 days and is only provided for backwards compatability.

```
  len(tag.find_all("div", recursive=False)
```